# Two instances of javascript slideshow not looping

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code running to loop through some divs in a fading slideshow. However it is not restarting when it gets to the end of the divs. I think this may be to do with duplicate function names or definitions though I'm not sure what needs to be done to fix it.

Once instance of the slideshow loops just fine.

Any help much appreciated!

```html
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var allBoxes = $("div.boxes").children("div");
    transitionBox(null, allBoxes.first());
});

function transitionBox(from, to) {
    function next() {
        var nextTo;
        if (to.is(":last-child")) {
            nextTo = to.closest(".boxes").children("div").first();
        } else {
            nextTo = to.next();
        }
        to.fadeIn(500, function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                transitionBox(to, nextTo);
            }, 30000);
        });
    }
    
    if (from) {
        from.fadeOut(500, next);
    } else {
        next();
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var allBoxes = $("div.sideboxes").children("div");
    transitionBox(null, allBoxes.first());
});

function transitionBox(from, to) {
    function next() {
        var nextTo;
        if (to.is(":last-child")) {
            nextTo = to.closest(".sideboxes").children("div").first();
        } else {
            nextTo = to.next();
        }
        to.fadeIn(500, function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                transitionBox(to, nextTo);
            }, 30000);
        });
    }
    
    if (from) {
        from.fadeOut(500, next);
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `to.closest(".sideboxes").children("div").first();` is getting the correct div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it in the end, just needed to define a different name for the second instance of transitionBox. See below:

```html
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var allBoxes = $("div.boxes").children("div");
    transitionBox(null, allBoxes.first());
});

function transitionBox(from, to) {
    function next() {
        var nextTo;
        if (to.is(":last-child")) {
            nextTo = to.closest(".boxes").children("div").first();
        } else {
            nextTo = to.next();
        }
        to.fadeIn(500, function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                transitionBox(to, nextTo);
            }, 30000);
        });
    }
    
    if (from) {
        from.fadeOut(500, next);
    } else {
        next();
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var allBoxes = $("div.sideboxes").children("div");
    transitionBox2(null, allBoxes.first());
});

function transitionBox2(from, to) {
    function next() {
        var nextTo;
        if (to.is(":last-child")) {
            nextTo = to.closest(".sideboxes").children("div").first();
        } else {
            nextTo = to.next();
        }
        to.fadeIn(500, function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                transitionBox2(to, nextTo);
            }, 30000);
        });
    }
    
    if (from) {
        from.fadeOut(500, next);
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```